# Expression for SSRS background cell colour

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, vba, reporting-services

I am trying to write an expression in SQL Server Data Tools for a report that will help with location of files on drives. Essentially my goal is to meet the following criteria:

> IF (DriveLetter = F: OR T:) AND (FileType = MDF OR NDF) THEN Green IF
>   (DriveLetter = G: OR U:) AND (FileType = LDF)        THEN Green ELSE
>   Red

This is what I tried:

```
IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" OR Fields!FileType.Value = "NDF"), "Green",
IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "G:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "U:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF"), "Green", "Red") )
```

And it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can achieve my requirements or see any mistakes in expression i wrote?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by craM, the statement should work.

You might want to try using Trim function as it your value may have trailing spaces.

```
IIF((Trim(Fields!DriveLetter.Value) = "F:" OR Trim(Fields!DriveLetter.Value) = "T:") AND (Trim(Fields!FileType.Value) = "MDF" OR Trim(Fields!FileType.Value) = "NDF"), "Green", IIF((Trim(Fields!DriveLetter.Value) = "G:" OR Trim(Fields!DriveLetter.Value) = "U:") AND (Trim(Fields!FileType.Value) = "LDF"), "Green", "Red") )
```

Comment: What do you mean by trailing spaces?

Comment: If a table field is defined as `Char` data type then it is padded with trailing spaces and if the field is defined as `Varchar` then it is not padded with trailing spaces. You might be comparing `F:          ` with `F:` which will not match.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding my own mistake. I completely forgot about the "=" sign before the expression!
My expression was correct all along minus forgetting the equals sign.

Answer (score -1):

It should work, looks like a typo: `NDF` VS `LDF`

try:

```
IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "T:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "MDF" OR Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF"), "Green",IIF((Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "G:" OR Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "U:") AND (Fields!FileType.Value = "LDF"), "Green", "Red") )
```

If thats not the case ensure that all your comparisons work.

I.e. test that:

```
IIF(Fields!DriveLetter.Value = "F:", "Green", "Red")
```

changes the color as it should.

Comment: No it was not a typo. Primary (MDF) and Secondary (NDF) data files should be on drives F or T while log files (LDF) are on G or U

Comment: Then you have a typo in your description `AND (FileType = MDF OR LDF)`, besides that the syntax of your IFF statement should work.